# Cakephp 3 Full Calendar setup

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Does anyone have any experience of getting this (Cake 2 plugin) working with Cakephp 3? Is it just case of copying the files to what should be their relevant places in Cake 3?

I've been trying for a couple of hours - installing under plugins doesn't work - complaints about a missing controller. I address that by copying the controller files into the controller folder but that makes no difference (I renamed a file to match the controller it was looking for only for Cake to then complain about another controller referred in the first).

Any help, even a simple what should go where, would be appreciated.

For clarity, the plugin I was referring to was: https://github.com/silasmontgomery/CakePHP-Full-Calendar-Plugin rather than the jQuery fullcalendar...

Comment: cake 2 is different from cake 3, there might be difference in syntax of plugins

Comment: Have you gone through https://github.com/silasmontgomery/CakePHP-Full-Calendar-Plugin  readme files

Comment: Yes. That process doesn't work due to the differences you mention. I know it can be done and intend to invest time in figuring it out.

Comment: Would it not be easier to just implement fullcalendar on its own. I did in 2x without the need for a plugin

Comment: I hope, following the readme files and updating the cakephp and its composer will be easy option rather than developing new one as per your version of cakephp

Comment: The readme includes installing it as a plugin, which doesn't work. Is there any chance you could post a quick 'what goes where' please mcgowan.b?

Answer (score 1):

A Cake 3 branch has been created by someone who knows a lot more about this than I.

It is here: [Cake 3 Full Calendar](https://github.com/curtisblack2004/CakePHP-Full-Calendar-Plugin/tree/3.x)

Tested, working.